# Have an issue with JDBC connector Clickhouse

Tags: pyspark, jdbc, clickhouse

I wrote a function that writes spark dataframe into Clickhouse DB like below:

```
def write_df_to_click_house(df, table_name, clickhouse_connection_obj):

clickhouse_driver = "com.github.housepower.jdbc.ClickHouseDriver"
batch_size = "200000"
num_partitions = "10"
jdbc_url = f"jdbc:clickhouse://**.**.**.**:**/**"
logger.info(jdbc_url)
df.write.mode("append").format("jdbc").option("driver", clickhouse_driver).option(
    "user", *****
).option("password", *****).option(
    "batchsize", batch_size
).option(
    "numPartitions", num_partitions
).jdbc(
    jdbc_url, table_name, "append"
)
```

When this function run and try to load data into Clickhouse I got this error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o450.jdbc.: com.github.housepower.exception.ClickHouseSQLException: RESPONSE_TABLES_STATUS_RESPONSE
```

Comment: Have you tried the official JDBC driver?

Comment: @GeoffGenz this one com.clickhouse.jdbc.ClickHouseDriver ?

Comment: Yes -- ClickHouse Inc. owns the clickhouse.com domain and officially supports various packages, including that JDBC driver.